# Installing Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, composer-php

How to install Laravel5.0, apache, mysql and php5.4 on Ubuntu?
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix all permissions problems between apache2 user and your current ubuntu user.

1. Add your current user to group www-data (the default apache2 user):

`sudo adduser <username> www-data`

2. Change ownership of project's directory (usually `/var/www`):

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`

3. Change group permissions:

`sudo chmod -R g+rwX /var/www`